# Diffie Hellman with authentication

Tags: java, security, network-programming, diffie-hellman, network-security

in this link:
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/security/ch13_07.htm
I found the implementation of Diffie Hellman exchange, but I don't undersand why it use X509EncodedKeySpec object;
Morover, how can I modify the program to avoid the "man in the middle" attack?
Thanks.

Comment: Add digital signatures.

Comment: How can i do this?
However, in the program uses X509EncodedKeySpec object (for certification).